# batch substitution of URLs in pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, url

I am working on SharePoint 2013 in a wiki library. I have hundreds of articles in there, and many of them have links to our old web server. I will migrate to a new web server soon, which will in this case lead to a different base URL, e.g. `http://server1.intranet.com/files/file1.pdf` to `http://perseus.intranet.com/storage/file1.pdf` .

Question: How can in search an replace all of these URLs?

I would assume that I can go to a database in the back (like WordPress) and conduct a search&replace operation there. However, I am new to SharePoint (I even don't know which tags to use), and advice is needed.

Comment: No to database, Powershell script might help.. Let someone jump in to guide you how..

Answer (score 0):

URL change means, you changing AAM? if yes then it will automatically update for all the Links unless you hard coded URL it.

Once you made the changes( update the AAM), then you have to make sure the Content Source reflecting the new URL of web App.

Now run a full crawl, it will remove the old url from index and put the new URL. May be need to run incremental crawl followed by full.

Comment: Thanks! The servers are both outside Sharepoint. Let it be that I link to articles on bbc.co.uk and they change their domain to bbc.com . All external. Need to replace part of the string.